# nullpointerexception in eclipse(android)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `NullPointerException` from Eclipse when running the below code, can't firgure it out exactly. This is code fore Android through Eclipse btw. I have tried moving the private class for `UpdateTimeTask` around because I believe that is the issue.

```
public class ClockWidgetXActivity extends Activity {
private UpdateTimeTask m_updateTime;
private Handler m_handler;
private TextView time;
private final int DELAY = 100;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time1);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Carre.ttf");
    time.setTypeface(font);
    time.setTextSize(65.f);
    time.setText(currentDateTimeString);
    m_updateTime = new UpdateTimeTask();

    m_handler = new Handler();
    m_handler.post(m_updateTime);

}  

private class UpdateTimeTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        time.setText(currentDateTimeString);

        m_handler.postDelayed(m_updateTime, DELAY);
    }
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.sokydevelopers.clockWidgetX.ClockWidgetXActivity$UpdateTimeTask.run(ClockWidgetXActivity.java:23)
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-01 03:26:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `time` variable is not initialized which is used in the task. You end up initializing a local in the onCreate.

```
TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time1);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
```

Do this instead,

```
 time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be:

```
m_updateTime = new UpdateTimeTask();
m_handler = new Handler();
```

update to:

```
m_handler = new Handler();
m_updateTime = new UpdateTimeTask();
```

Try to comment out this line first to confirm:

```
m_handler.postDelayed(m_updateTime, DELAY);
```

then un-comment it.